# MVC in the controller decide to open a popup or continue to nextpage

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have the following scenario:

When the user click on button next, I have to do some validation that must be done in the controller.

If there is an error, it will show the error messages in a popup with a Yes to continue or No to cancel and close the popup.

But if there are no errors, user will continue to next page without showing a popup.

Here is what I have:

```
[ActionName(PA.FlowActionName), AcceptPost("nextAanvullen")]
[NoAsyncTimeout]
public ActionResult Pagina_nextAanvullen(OffrerenFlow flow)
{
    var medewerkers = ((MedewerkersAanvullenPakket)(flow.CurrentBusinessObject)).Medewerkers;
    //validate here
    if (true) // for test use true
    {
        var blok = medewerkers.Deelnemers;
        return View("DeelnemersFout", medewerkers); // This doesnt open a popup
    }
    else
    {
       // Go to next page
        DoWorkEventHandler handler = (o, e) =>
        {
            AsyncManager.Parameters["navigation"] = Navigate(new NavigationData<OffrerenFlow>((OffrerenFlow)flow), PA.Next,
                true);
        };

        ExecuteAsyncMethod(handler);
    }
}
```

I am not getting an popup, the view just display the view "DeelnemersFout". I need it to be in a popup. Any suggestions are welkom

Comment: You'll have to use javaScript and call the method asynchronously

Comment: You need to use ajax if you want to stay on the same page and display a popup.

Comment: how? to use ajax when  you are in the controller?

Comment: Either call the controller via ajax just to do the validation, and let the page decide to continue or not, _or_ return the error messages to the page in the response (e.g. via the viewdata or someting) and let the page run some script to show a popup. You can't trigger a popup from the controller, all you can do is give the page information which it can use to decide whether to show a popup

Answer (score 0):

Assign a value in ViewBag inside IF block

```
if (true) // for test use true
    {
        ViewBag.ShowPopup = true;
        var blok = medewerkers.Deelnemers;
        return View("DeelnemersFout", medewerkers); // This doesnt open a popup
    }
```

and on Cshtml capture this value in a javascript variable and check if there is a value in this variable or not, and show the popup accordingly.